# how to minimize size of videoplayer in android phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I display video using videoplayer plugin for android phonegap.The video disdplayed by videoplayer in full
screen.I want to display video in haif screen.

How I will change the size of videoplayer?

please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the videoplayer.java code here - https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/VideoPlayer/src/com/phonegap/plugins/video/VideoPlayer.java 
 
to take into consideration the height and width, so that the holder can resize accordingly. Check this example so to what code to add the the java file of the plugin - http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

try this out and then update if u face some issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I used that videoplayer.java.I see your 2nd link.How to add width and height according to that linkin videoplayer.java.Please give some example for modifing videoplayer.java.give example.Please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: please guide me.I don't know how to change videoplayer.java.thanks in advance.